# XAML Databound TextBlock showing unknown character glyph

Tags: xaml

Question: Why won't my databound text render as text

When I am using databound TextBlock controls, the output in my Windows App shows as Squares, like it can't figure out what to render the text as.  If I put actual text in the Text property, it displays normally.

```
<RelativePanel x:Name="BasicInfo" RightOf="ProfilePicture">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="FirstName" Text="{Binding FirstName}"
                           TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="LastName" Text="{Binding LastName}" 
                       TextWrapping="NoWrap" Padding="3,0,0,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="EmailAddress" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding EmailAddress}"
                           TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="10,2,0,0" />
                    <TextBlock x:Name="PhoneNumber" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding PhoneNumber}"
                           TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="10,2,0,0" />
                </StackPanel>
            </RelativePanel>
            <RelativePanel x:Name="AddressInfo" Below="BasicInfo" RightOf="ProfilePicture" Margin="0, 20, 0, 0">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="Address1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Address1}"
                               TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="Address2" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Text="{Binding Address2}"
                               TextWrapping="NoWrap" TextAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="City" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Text="{Binding City}"
                               TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                        <TextBlock>,</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="State" Text="{Binding State}"
                               TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="3,0,0,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="ZipCode" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding ZipCode}"
                               TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </RelativePanel>
```

Here is what the output looks like:[image]

Comment: Looks like, an encoding issue. What are the XAML encoding and you code source encoding?

Answer (score 0):

we can try in xaml.cs page

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate
                    {
                        listboxname.ItemsSource = Resultclassname;

                   });
```